# Why Coefficient of determination equal to the square of the correlation?

Tags: regression, correlation

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination), it is stated that the Coefficient of Determination and the Square of Coefficient Correlation are equivalent.

But in general, the coefficient of determination is equal to $R^2=1 - \frac{RSS}{TSS}$ . Where $RSS = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(\hat{y}_i - y_i)^2$ and $TSS = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i - \bar{y})^2$.

And for OLS model or univariate linear regression, one can [prove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explained_sum_of_squares) that $R^2 = \frac{ESS}{TSS}$ assuming that sum of residual equal to 0, where $ESS=\sum_{i=1}^n(\hat{y} - \bar{y})^2$.

My question is, How to mathematically prove that the Coefficient of Determination and the Square of Coefficient Correlation are equivalent using the original definition of the Coefficient of Determination?

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: he obvious answer to the question in the title is "by definition"; just as the square of the SD is the variance. // Your actual question seems to be about the the practical interpretation, but you have not made that clear. Should you final sentence have "... prove that these two indexes are equivalent?" If so, what do you mean by that--in addition to the defining formulas? // In simple linear regression of $y$ on $x,$ both $|r_{xy}| = 1$ and $R^2 = 1$ indicate 'perfect fit' to a line, thus making pooible perfect prediction of $y$ once the corresponding $x$ is knowm.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry for not being clear on the question. Yes, it is as you mentioned. I just wonder how can one mathematically prove that the Coefficient of Determination is equivalent to the Square of Correlation Coefficient as stated in Wikipedia using the original definition of Coefficient of Determination in my question.

Comment: Maybe you want to partition total sum of squares to get something like $s_{y|x}^2 = \frac{n-1}{n-2}s_y^2(1-r^2).$

Comment: This will be sort of a mess in Comment mode but: in R set up regression with `
`x = rnorm(10, 100, 15);` `e = rnorm(10, 0, 2); be.0 = 7; be.1 = 2;`
`y = be.0+be.1*x+e`, then `r = cor(x,y)` returns  $0.9938263$ and
`summary(lr(y ~ x))` shows
 $R^2 = .9938$ and resid SE $2.558.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coefficient of determination is squared correlation coefficient between fitted values ***ŷ*** and dependent values ***y***. Here is the proof, where ***e*** is the residual. We assume that basic properties of linear regression are satisfied.
[image]

The covariance between ***e*** and  ***ŷ*** equals zero from definition. Then, squared coefficient of correlation is the coefficient of determination.

Comment: I agree that this is not much of an answer, but the main fault is with the question, which IMHO is where the down-vote belongs. (Thus my +1 to cancel someone's unexplained -1)